# In argparse, is it possible to use -h option for anything other than 'help'?

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I am writing a code where I have to pass a hostname as an optional argument. It is also required to be passed with -h option.

Usage:

```
./program.py -h hostname
```

Argparse by default use -h for printing help. Is it possible to override that somehow?

Comment: I Python you can override anything - but it would be a blatant violation of the [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: @PauloScardine Agree, but this is for an assignment and I don't have much of an option here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No problem, all you have to do is pass `add_help=False` to the `ArgumentParser` constructor.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
```

If you still want to have the help functionality, however, it's not so easy. In that case, I would recommend just calling your host argument `-H` or something else. If you really want to do it, this is one method, but it's definitely a hack:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser._add_action(argparse._HelpAction(
    option_strings=['-H', '--help'],
    help='Show this help message and exit'
))
```

EDIT: thanks to @chepner for pointing out a cleaner way to add the help functionality:

```
parser.add_argument('-H', '--help', action='help',
    help='show this help message and exit')
```

Comment: That was of great help. Do you know why args.accumulate() wouldn't get printed when I do that?

Comment: I added a method you could still use to print help if you wanted. Could you post more code of where you're calling args.accumulate?

Comment: You don't need to instantiate `_HelpAction` directly. You can do what `ArgumentParser` does when `add_help` is true: add the keyword argument `action='help'`.